# websocketを使いpythonプログラム同士でPiCameraから取得したデータのやり取りをしたい

Tags: python, 画像, websocket, pil, base64

送信側

```
import websocket
from picamera import camera
import io

class WebSocketClient(object):
    def __init__(self, url, io_loop=None, extra_headers=None):
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(url)
        self.ws.on_open = self.on_open
        self.state = True
        self.picamera = camera.PiCamera()
        self.picamera.resolution = (920,690) # 4:3
        self.picamera.rotation = 270

    def on_open(self):
        self.state = True
        print("open")
        while(self.state):
            stream = io.BytesIO()
            for pixels in Picamera.capture_continuous(stream, "png"):
                stream.seek(0)
                data = stream.read()
                print(type(data))
                self.ws.send(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(False)
    ws_client = WebSocketClient("ws://SERVER")
    ws_client.ws.run_forever()
```

受信側

```
from websocket_server import WebsocketServer
import threading
import json
import sys
import requests
import urllib

import traceback
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
from io import BytesIO
import io


class message:
    def __init__(self, Type, data):
        self.type = str(Type)
        self.data = str(data)

    def to_json(self):
        return json.dumps(self.__dict__, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)


def new_client(client, server):
    print("new")


def message_received(client, server, Message):
    try:
        if(len(Message) > 100):
            Message = Message.encode('UTF-8')
            img_from_str = Image.open(Message)
            img_from_str.save('test.png')
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()


# Main
if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = WebsocketServer(port=12345, host='SERVER')
    server.set_fn_new_client(new_client)
    server.set_fn_message_received(message_received)
    print("start")
    server.run_forever()
```

としているのですが、PILのImage.open()を使ったところでエラーが出ます

画像データをpython3同士 / websocketにて送受信するサンプルが見つからず、組み合わせて書いているのですが
エンコード/デコードあたりがあまり自信がありません。
ご助言いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

そのwebsocketライブラリを利用してるかはわかりませんが、Binaryが送受信可能なAPIを探してみると良いと思います。
`websockets`でのかんたんなサンプルは次のとおりです。画像のPATHは適宜変更してください。

client側

```py
# client.py
import asyncio
import websockets

async def sendImage():
    uri = "ws://localhost:8765"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        with open("source/sample.jpg", "rb") as f:
          data = f.read()
          await websocket.send(data)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(sendImage())
```

server側

```py
# server.py
import asyncio
import websockets

async def receiveImage(websocket, path):
    image = await websocket.recv()
    with open("output/sample.jpg", "wb")  as f:
      f.write(image)
      print("Save output/sample.jpg")

start_server = websockets.serve(receiveImage, "localhost", 8765)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

### 参考

- https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html
- https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#websockets.protocol.WebSocketCommonProtocol.send
- https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#websockets.protocol.WebSocketCommonProtocol.recv

Comment: ありがとうございます。使用しているライブラリについて記入しました。on_open,on_closeなどの関数が必要なため、こちらを使用しています。

Comment: 送信側でopcodeを設定する必要があったのが問題でした。websocketはライブラリが多く、誤認していた様です。失礼しました。